# Linguagem C : "fseek.c: No such file or directory" fazendo um Unix Tac

Tags: c

Pessoal estou tentando fazer um desafio de programação [esse aqui](https://osprogramadores.com/desafios/d07/). Não é um desafio muito díficil porém meu script não tem o comportamento esperado, em arquivos pequenos funciona porém em arquivos maiores como de 1GB eu recebo `segmentation fault` Analizando com o gdb o erro é esse:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e55cb0 in __GI_fseek (fp=0x555555559220,
    offset=900935887, whence=0) at fseek.c:35
35      fseek.c: No such file or directory.
```

Muitos vão ler e dizer "O fseek não encontra o diretorio ou o arquivo" Porém esse script funciona com arquivos pequenos encontra, talvez perdeu o caminho durante o processo.

Meu código é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//O programa deve ler arquivos de qualquer tamanho e funcionar com um limite de
//512MB de memória (ler o arquivo inteiro em memória não é uma alternativa
//viável).

void reversePrint(char *sentence) {
  long long i = 0;

  while(sentence[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
  }
  if((i> 0) && sentence[i-1] == '\n') {
    i -= 2;
    for(; i >= 0; i--) {
      putchar(sentence[i]);
    }
    puts("");
  }else {
    for(; i >= 0; i--) {
      putchar(sentence[i]);
    }
    puts("");
  }

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  FILE *file;
  char ch;

  if( ! *++argv){
    fputs("Usage: tac <file>\n",stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  if((file = fopen(*argv, "r")) == NULL) {
    perror("error openig file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }



  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

  long size;

  size = ftell(file);

  char bufferLine[10000];

  long j = 0;


  for ( size -=2 ; size >= 0; size--) {

      fseek(file, size, SEEK_SET);


      if(ferror(file)) {
        perror("seek error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      bufferLine[j] = getc(file);

      if((bufferLine[j] == '\n') || size == 0) {

          bufferLine[j+1] = '\0';
          reversePrint(bufferLine);
          j = -1;
      }
      j++;
  }

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Para poder testar com o arquivo grande no qual me referi [este é o link de download](https://osprogramadores.com/files/d07/1GB.txt.gz)

Quero muito saber por que estou recebendo esse erro.

Answer (score 0):

Bem havia 3 erros no meu código o principal.

1º Erro:

```
char bufferLine[10000];
```

Pode haver linhas que possuem mais de 10 mil bytes antes do proximo `\n`

2º erro:

O comportamento do ftell para stream de texto é indefinido

3º :

A função reversePrint estava imprimindo bytes nulos.